# css drop down menu force to top not under

Tags: html, css

I have CSS code for a dropdown menu. I'm creating 3 menus with the same CSS where each one is displayed under the other. The html is produced from a Perl script as data is created for each search.

```css
#menu {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

ul#menu {
    list-style: none;
    top: 1.1em;
    position: relative;
    background: #171e35;
    padding: 1em 1em;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

ul#menu ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 34px;
    left: -30px;
    width: 250px;
    text-align: left;  
    *width: 100%; /* IE7 hack*/
}
    
ul#menu li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}

ul#menu li {
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
}

ul#menu li a {
    padding: 0.5em 1.0em 0.9em 1.0em;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.submenu li a {
    display:block;
}

#menu ul li a {
    background: #171e35;
    left;
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Menu</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="$site_url>Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.cgi>See ALL</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.cgi>Quick Availability</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

<!-- And the second menu code: -->

<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Choose</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="$site_url>Blah</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.cgi>Blah2</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.cgi>Blah3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

<!-- And third is same -->
```

**PROBLEM**: The top/first menu drops down underneath the next menu so it can't be read. Is there code that will force the active drop down to be on top?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about adding the `z-index` property to your `ul#menu li:hover ul`, and adding to it some value like this:

```css
#menu {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul#menu {
  list-style: none;
  top: 1.1em;
  position: relative;
  background: #171e35;
  padding: 1em 1em;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

ul#menu ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 34px;
  left: -30px;
  width: 250px;
  text-align: left;
  *width: 100%;
  /* IE7 hack*/
}

ul#menu li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  z-index: 100;
}

ul#menu li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
}

ul#menu li a {
  padding: 0.5em 1.0em 0.9em 1.0em;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.submenu li a {
  display: block;
}

#menu ul li a {
  background: #171e35;
  left;
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu">
  <li><a href="#">Menu</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="$site_url">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="index.cgi>See ALL</a></li>
            <li><a href=" index.cgi>Quick Availability</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul id="menu">
  <li><a href="#">Choose</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="$site_url>Blah</a></li>
            <li><a href=" index.cgi>Blah2</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="index.cgi">Blah3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks.. seems to work. Tried this (z-index: 100;) before with a value of '1'. and it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should fix html tags. All your a tags are missing their end tag.

```
<ul id="menu">
<li><a href="#">Menu</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="$site_url>Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.cgi>See ALL</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.cgi>Quick Availability</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Should become

```
<ul id="menu">
<li><a href="#">Menu</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="$site_url">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.cgi">See ALL</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.cgi">Quick Availability</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```